# discord.js read reactions from old message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I started to write an discord bot with discord.js 11.5.

I don't want to use an event like `client.on()` because it takes days until everybody added his reactions and it's in a small channel which is always cleaned up with a few messages only.

I'm fetching older messages via `fetchMessages()` extract a specific message and want read the existing reactions from it. But I'm stuck with reading the reactions from the message.

Something like

```
message.reactions.array()
```

returns an empty array.

The docs mentions that it's not possible to listen to old message reactions, only in 12.x it is. but I don't use a listener, so I guess this limitation is not relevant in this case.

Is there any way to access reactions on old messages?

According to Discord docs it should be possible:
https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-reactions

Answer (score -1):

I guess you took a look at the [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) docs.

You can try `fetchMessages()` and then `awaitReactions()` or `createReactionCollector()` to receive the Reactions of the message. But i dont know if this works for your case.

Comment: Yes I checked the docs.I think they are both for upcoming reactions and not for existing reactions.

Comment: Just tested with awaitReactions() and createReactionCollector() but it does not find any reaction.

Answer (score -1):

I did something wrong on my 1st try.

Using `message.reactions` is working when used correctly.

Comment: Can you update your answer to describe the correct use? Right now this isn't an answer to the question — folks reading this wouldn't know what they need to do to actually get reactions to a message.